# Unable to override @salesforce/community/basePath mock within jest test

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript, unit-test, lwc-jest

I'm trying to mock the `@salesforce/community/basePath` scoped module with different values for each jest test.

I've mocked it globally :

```
jest.mock(
    "@salesforce/i18n/lang",
     () => {
         return {
             default: { code: "fr", label: "FR" },
         };
     },
{ virtual: true }
);
```

This works great as I'm able to see my component use the label from the `lang` property.

Is it possible to mock this scoped module with a different value? I tried inserting it within my `describe` block like the following :

```
//I've declared the above snippet outside of the describe block

describe("Component", () => {
    it("change label", ... {
      jest.mock(
          "@salesforce/i18n/lang",
           () => {
               return {
                   default: { code: "jp", label: "JA" },
               };
           },
     { virtual: true }
     );
  }
}
```

Why is jest picking up the mock I created globally instead of the one that is within the scope of the test?

Answer (score 0):

> Why is jest picking up the mock I created globally instead of the one
> that is within the scope of the test?

In pure jest terms, I would expect the behavior you noted based on the code you shared. There's this large discussion on a closed jest [issue](https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/2582) that has some good information

> So jest.mock is being hoisted to the function scope, that's why it won't work with requires (and definitely not imports which are hoisted to module scope) if you call it inside a function other than describe (which is treated specially by Jasmine).
> Your jest.mock call will be hoisted to the top of that very function (not the module), that's why it won't work the way you expect.

You'll notice the key consideration is the scope and the fact that `jest.mock()` is hoisted - this is covered in [Jest Mocking](https://github.com/kentcdodds/how-jest-mocking-works):

> Jest will automatically hoist jest.mock calls to the top of the module
> (before any imports)

This is how your global `jest.mock()`, even though being defined after the import, is able to provide the mocked value when the module is imported. Along with that, it also explains why, your test-specific `jest.mock()`, has no impact - it would be set after the global mock/import has occurred as it isn't within the module scope along with the import.

This is why, in [Jest documentation](https://jestjs.io/docs/manual-mocks), there's mention of needing to mock modules globally

> Note: In order to mock properly, Jest needs jest.mock('moduleName') to
> be in the same scope as the require/import statement.

You'll notice in that above threads, there are discussions/ways to achieve different values for mocked modules (`beforeEach`, `require()`, `jest.resetModules`) - unfortunately the key consideration with your use case is you're dealing with a *salesforce* schema scoped import that returns a *value*.

[Jest Test Patterns and Mock Dependencies](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.unit_testing_using_jest_patterns) has a section for `@salesforce` scoped imports where it mentions the following (in the context of `@salesforce/label`):

> In Jest tests, we use a jest-transformer to convert the
> @salesforce/label import statement into a variable declaration

The example they use is custom labels, but `@salesforce/i18n/lang` also uses a jest-transformer that utilizes the same method ([stringScopedImportTransform](https://github.com/salesforce/lwc-test/blob/f9aba73e0898f45cc6fafb24c6ff470f7af25c61/packages/%40lwc/jest-transformer/src/transforms/utils.js#L41)) to do the same as you can see under [i18n-scoped-import.js](https://github.com/salesforce/lwc-test/blob/master/packages/%40lwc/jest-transformer/src/transforms/i18n-scoped-import.js). The transformer returns a *value* - the default being  `en` even if you don't import/mock in your jest test. A comment in the method shows the following

> This approach gives these special imports a default value to ease
> testing components with imports, but allows test authors to call
> `jest.mock()` to provide their own value.

However, this behavior seems to be the blocker for you as it's done globally and it's transformed by default if you don't. Which means I don't believe there is a way to mock a different value for these *special* imports within individuals tests in a LWC jest.

To accomplish what you want, you could still create multiple jest test files

- `lwc_FR.test.js`
- `lwc_JA.test.js`
- ...

Where you change this value in the global `jest.mock` to test different languages - just make sure to provide a similar mock as to what is actually returned

```
jest.mock(
    "@salesforce/i18n/lang",
     () => {
         return {
            "fr"
         };
     },
     { virtual: true }
);
```